# Is it possible to view Google Chrome bookmarks and history from the terminal

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to view Google Chrome bookmarks and history by using command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **Bookmarks** is a UTF-8 plain text file  in `JSON` format:

```
$ file ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks
.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

- `google-chrome-beta`

  Depending on your version of Chrome
- `Default`

  Depending on your profile

To view the bookmars use this command:

```
less ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks
```

or with `jq`, a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

and run with this command to see the whole structure:

```
jq '.' ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks
```

or with this command to see an entry, eg. `checksum`:

```
jq '.checksum' ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks
```

or all bookmarks in the bookmark bar:

```
jq '.roots.bookmark_bar.children' ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Bookmarks
```

---

The **History** is a binary file in `SQLite format 3`:

```
$ file ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/History           
.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/History: SQLite 3.x database
```

- `google-chrome-beta`

  Depending on your version of Chrome
- `Default`

  Depending on your profile

**To query the database, Chrome must be completely closed. Or you have to  create a copy of the file and use that copy.**

To view the history you need to install sqlite3:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Start sqlite3 with:

```
sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/History
```

and list all tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
downloads             meta                  urls                
downloads_url_chains  segment_usage         visit_source        
keyword_search_terms  segments              visits
```

or to see all downloads:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE 1;
```

Alternatively, a GUI may be used:

- `sqlitebrowser`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
  ```

  and start with:

  ```
  sqlitebrowser ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/History
  ```
- `sqliteman`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install sqliteman
  ```

  and start with:

  ```
  sqliteman ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/History
  ```

Comment: Gd answer, but still can't see history without instlling sqlite? Is'nt some app that just read sqlite DB?

Comment: More tools added

Comment: on osX 10.11: `jq . "/Users/john/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks"`